# blackberry image effect

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to change image effect of an image like sepia, charcoal, monochrome, emboss, negative etc.
also I want to change hue, saturation, brightness, contrast also.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract image data using `Bitmap.getARGB(...)` to an array. API link [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#getARGB%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Then you can apply any filtering effect on that data to get you image ready. You can check this [link](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html), to get some helpful hints about how to apply filter on images.

And to make an image with the prepared data use `Bitmap.setARGB(...)`. API link [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#setARGB%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).